# jQuery MVC 5 dropdown list to session variable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

im trying to set a Session var with the value of a drop down list, im not to fused if its the text of a value,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slid").on("change", function () {

        var selectedLang = document.getElementById("slid");
        var selectedItem = selectedLang.options[selectedLang.selectedIndex].text;

        var myvar = selectedItem.text;

        '@{Session["temp"] = "' + myvar + '"; }';

        alert('@{Session["temp"] = "' + myvar + '"; }');


        alert(this.value);

    })
```

my alert(this.value) works but im trying to set that to the Session var and im getting nothing

if i say

```
    var text = this.textContent;

    alert(text);
```

this returns all not just the one

UPDATE

ok seing as $.post isnt working

im trying to just use a ajax postback

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("UpdateLang")",
            type: "POST",
            data: { model: JSON.stringify(myVar) },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (response) {
                alert("somthing"); // response.responseText
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
```

this also fails

any help thanks

Comment: if you're trying to set a session variable in javascript, this will not work. the C# code is only run on the server, not on the client.

Comment: yes i know that. you cannot set a server variable from javascript without a postback.

Comment: ok thanks, nothing happening with the post back at all now,

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. You need to send the client-side variable back to your server. You can use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to do this:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slid").on("change", function () {
        // This is the jQuery way of finding selected option's text
        var myVar = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        // Post the value to your server. You should do some error handling here
        $.post("/MyController/SetSession", {
            myVariable: myVar
        });
    });
});
```

**MyController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetSession(string myVariable) {
    // Set to Session here.
    Session["temp"] = myVariable;
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

**Note:** Session is not really meant for storing short-lived information. Perhaps you could use [TempData](http://sampathloku.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/how-to-use-aspnet-mvc-tempdata-properly.html)?

Comment: im sure this will work but iv tried to impliment this and I get nothing,

Comment: so the thing that actually not working now is the post back, I get the selected ID set to the myVar varible but after that it fails the $.post isnt doing a thing :S

Comment: If you know as to why a postback like your wont work in MVC 5 can you state why and Ill make yours at the right answer